# Change target build on android studio

Tags: android, target-platform

I want to change the target build for my android project in android studio. I am not talking about the API-level. Trying to find how i make my project build for different layouts depending on what target. So in other words.

if target = build1. Then it will load build1's layout and drawable's. Then if i choose target = build2. Then it will chose the layout and drawable's accordingly

I know it is called targets in iOS. But i have no idea what it is called in Android. Therefore i cant find a good answer to my problem.

Comment: can you show build.gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding types in Android Studio are **buildTypes** or **productFlavors**

You will find the documentation here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide